# DistanceTo() incorrect distance between two places

Tags: java, android, gps, maps, distance

In my app I use the method "DistanceTo()" to get the distance between to places, but don't works correctly!! This is my code for this distance:

```
double  latitudine;
double longitudine;
latitudine = 40.17;
longitudine = 24.9;
Location qui = new Location("Corrente");
qui.setLatitude(latitudine);
qui.setLatitude(longitudine);

double  latitudine2;
double longitudine2;
latitudine2 = 40.16;
longitudine2 = 25;
Location due = new Location("Corrente2");
due.setLatitude(latitudine2);
due.setLatitude(longitudine2);
float b =  qui.distanceTo(due);
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "DESTINAZIONE KILOMETRI b:" + b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The toast show to me 11077.14 meters, but the distance should be 8.5 km!! as shown in these sites: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html http://www.mapdevelopers.com/distance_from_to.php
In this case the difference is for about 3km, but sometimes the difference is sometimes the difference is even more!! Please help me! Why this code doesn't work correctly? Thanks

Comment: You can try the map utils http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/ if it helps

Comment: why do you think it should be 8.5? the first link says: 11.17

Comment: @pskink the first link says 8.570 km! Please, put the correct coordinates

Comment: ok what is latitudine of the first point? you are calling `qui.setLatitude(latitudine); qui.setLatitude(longitudine);` so what is meaningful?

Comment: @pskink ah ok well!! ahah now I see well to set the longitude

Comment: @pskink assurdo, ora funziona! ahahah please, write your answer and I will vote it!! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not calling `setLongitude` on both `Locations`, you need:

```
qui.setLongitude(longitudine);
due.setLongitude(longitudine2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Might want to take a look at [Point2D.Distance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html#distance(double,%20double,%20double,%20double)) instead. It returns

> the distance between the two sets of specified coordinates.

Comment: in fact I set the latitude and longitude of The Other One In, there are two sets of specified coordinates I suppose